# Keep Oracle connection open when disconnected from network

Tags: oracle, session, connection

Is it possible to keep an Oracle connection open when PC is disconnected from LAN and reconnected again. Maybe you can keep the connection alive even if the user removes his laptop from desk (connected by LAN) and go to a meeting-room where he automatically connects to WLAN.

Application is a Windows Forms Application using the ODP.NET provider.

Today my application crashes and user has to logon again. I have no idea if this can be changed.

Comment: Keeping connections open indefinitely is probably not a good idea.  Maybe have your app check the connection before execution, and connect again?

Comment: Reconnection is difficult in my application, because you loose content from temporary tables and package variables, for example. They belong to current session only.

Comment: Sorry.  Maybe someone knows of a solution.  Probably not a good design to assume a connection is enabled forever.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use shared or dedicated server processes? If shared, then your UGA is kept in SGA, so, all the user data will be available after reconnect.

Comment: I don't know, how can I check (or change) it?

Comment: You can run DBCA (Database configuration assistant) to check the configuration of your database. But I agree with the comments from above,it is not good idea to keep your session active despite the connection has already been closed. If you want, you can add a workaround, for example, you can save all the data you want when connection was closed and restore it when user is online

Comment: Well, the entire application logic is defined in PL/SQL packages. It would be a big work. In this case the application will not support "reconnect after network disconnect"